# Moderators can't merge questions any more?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags, moderators, merged-questions

I had flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185667/naming-destructured-argument-objects) with

> Please merge the accepted answer into the duplicate

but when reviewing my flag history I see that it was resolved by a moderator as

> helpful - we can't do that

I can't believe that, you did it successfully before :-) Was this feature removed from the moderator tools, or what happened? If it's still possible, please take action.

Comment: Moderators can merge one accepted answer into a question that already got an accepted answer? Which of them was then still accepted and had the other one "suffer" a loss of 15 points?

Comment: @Tom: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39862/what-happens-to-both-accepted-answers-during-a-merge

Comment: That flag makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @YvetteColomb To be fair, it *does* say "merge the answer"... it could've been a bit clearer (e.g. "merge these two questions please").

Comment: @TylerH always a pleasure to see you! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That was me. I read the flag completely literally. I thought you wanted to merge the answers. A complete brain *boing*. So sorry.

Comment: Ok, shall I flag it again?

Comment: @Bergi: is that answer so much different and better that in needs moving across? It covers the exact same ground as the accepted answer on the other post (with a minor note on the use of `const` vs `let`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the explanation "*You cannot do it directly in the arguments, but you can extract the values afterward*" is crisp and clear and to the point, which is what I was missing at the other answers. The answers have a very similar quality level, and I thought it would be fair to have Quentin's answer presented alongside the others in the canonical.