# How to flag dozens of almost identical answers

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers, clean-up

There are a lot of questions asking about importing content from websites (web scraping) using [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) formulas. Researching for a canonical Q&A, I found there are dozens of bad questions having almost identical answers saying:

> It's not possible by using Google Sheets formulas.

---

*Note*: This is not the same as two users posting the almost identical answers to the same question the same day. This question is about two cases,

1. the same user posting "duplicate answers" to multiple questions (see below)
2. multiple users posting an answer originally posted to another question to new questions giving or not appropriate attribution, but not tailoring the new answer to the question (usually the question doesn't include enough details in order to warrant a tailored answer).

---

Some answers say that it's not possible to import the content using Google Sheets formulas because the it is loaded by the website using JavaScript, others because the webmaster / developer have established measures to protect the website content from web scraping.

Few of these answers also include a slight tailoring effort, like including a screenshot showing how the source website looks when opening it with JavaScript disabled.

---

Note: There are other answers that might provide a different answer or might say the same, but provide workarounds. Also there are many cases where the answerer do what I think should be done by the OP, but that is something to not be discussed here. Please keep this post about how to report dozens of duplicate answers.

---

I have already submitted flagged some answers:

Accepted

- 5 flags for single answers from one user, all of them accepted.
- 2 flags for single answers from two different users, all of them accepted.
- 1 flags for multiple answers (4) from the same user posted during a single month. Accepted but only the answer that was flagged was deleted.

What is the best way to report the other duplicate answers? Should I keep reporting one by one? Does it make sense to make some sort of task list and share it with moderators and others that might like to join to clean up the site from almost identical answers?

- After skimming the false positives from a search using the user id and certain keywords, it gives around 60 duplicate answers
- I'm afraid that there might additional dozens duplicate answers that might be found making variants of the above search

Related

- [Should I mod-flag duplicate answers for deletion, or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380811/1595451)
- [How about adding a "duplicate answer" manual flag type?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398644/1595451)

---

#### Additional details addressed to reply to clarification requests.

**Google Sheets**

1. The Google Sheets bult-in functions used for importing data are [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en), [IMPORTFEED](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337?hl=en), [IMPORTHMTL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en), [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) and [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).
   NOTE: I don't use "web scraping" term in questions about using IMPORTRANGE.
2. The built-in functions requires a URL using http or https protocols. They are only able to do HTTP GET requests. Examples:

   - `IMPORTDATA("http://www.census.gov/2010census/csv/pop_change.csv")`.
   - `IMPORTFEED("http://news.google.com/?output=atom")`.
   - `IMPORTHTML("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_India","table",4)`.
   - `IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing", "//a/@href")`.
   - `IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")`.
3. I posted this self-answered question in Web Applications SE [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)
4. Google Sheets uses Google Apps Script to create custom functions. Some common names used for Google Sheets custom functions in Stack Overflow questions for importing data are IMPORTJSON and IMPORTFROMWEB.

**Are these **questions** which have almost identical answers duplicates of each other?**

I'm gold tag badge holder and already closed as duplicate few of these questions that only have an almost identical answer. Questions that have other answers, i.e., that the answerer took the time to analyse the website and offer workarounds like using a different Google Sheets function or research for an alternative data sources I didn't close them yet. Note: This is not something that I revisit from time to time when I found new questions that might be closed as duplicate.

Comment: If you think answers aren't useful, downvote them. Are you doing that?

Comment: For illustration, can you add some examples? It isn't clear where the scraping takes place. E.g., is it importing from files which have been created by other means (outside of Google Sheets)?

Comment: Are these **questions** not duplicates of each other? If not, why not? What is specific about each asker's situation that merits a separate question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Just added additional details at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Just added additional details at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @RobertLongson Please see [Canonical question for importing content from dynamic websites using IMPORTHTML / IMPORTXML Google Sheets functions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422451/)

Comment: I noticed something similar on other tags, where someone asks X but someone says a clear-cut "it's not possible". A couple of minutes later, someone posts an answer showing how to do it without gaslighting the viewer. Usually those get downvoted to oblivion as some other pointed out, but feel free to delete/flag for attention if you think it's worth it.

Comment: @NordineLotfi This post is about a more complex case, the "it's not possible" answer is an almost identical answer of other dozens answers to questions about the same tool, specifically Google Sheets formulas, used to do the same task, in this case web-scraping, with slight variations i.e. different URL and different DOM node.

Answer (score 12):

If a person posts multiple (almost) identical answers and it seems like it is more of a mistake due to them not knowing better/that they should vote/flag the questions as duplicates, I would start by asking them in chat or the comments of one of their answers (and telling them about duplicates).

In case of the person seemingly knowing better or it harming the site or continuing after being asked not to (or if the user is really posting lots of almost-identical answers), I would raise a custom mod flag on *one of the answers* explaining the situation like the following:

> This user has posted almost identical answers to  questions.

In general, for custom flags, one flag on one post should be enough for general behaviour, there is typically no need to raise multiple custom/mod flags for the same thing if it's about the same user.

If the user also provides other (non-duplicate) answers, I would also attach a search query showing those duplicate answers if possible I would use the query operators `is:a user:<user-id>` for filtering for answers of that user. Operators like `code:` might also be useful for filtering these duplicate answers.

But before doing any of these, check if they are the same content-wise. If they are posting answers that look similar but are actually solving different problems (maybe the style of answering of that particular user or the topic the user is focusing being in a way so that most answers to that topic look very similar but actually differ content-wise), it could also be possible that it is fine.

Disclaimer: This is just my personal opinion.

Comment: So far I was not able to find how to get advantage of `code:`.  I just sent a flag with this search `https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D+import*ml+is%3Aanswer+disable+javascript+user%3Aredacted+-update+-run+-%22this+is+all%22+url%3Ai.stack.imgur.com` hopefully the mods will find it helpful.

Comment: You don't _have to_ use the `code:` operator but it can be useful if e.g. all of those answers contain (almost) the same piece of code.

Comment: @dan1st According to [Makoto's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421378/1595451) to [Code searching at the end of 2022](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421377/1595451) it might be better to use Google.

Comment: Use whatever works best for you - as long as the moderators can (easily) see what you want to show them.

Comment: Anecdote: Including a search in a flag doesn't caused any "special" effect other than it take a bit longer then the previous similar flags which might be unrelated to having the the search (the flag was marked as helpful the flagged answer was deleted, as all the previous flags, but thats it, the other answers returned by the search were still there). This occurred few days ago. I just found a FAQ on Meta SE with the explanation (added an adaptation as an answer).

Answer (score -2):

For those who decide to flag almost identical answers, as a complement to previous answer (adapted from [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/289691)),

> ### 4. Go hunt for more
>
> Moderators have enough to do already - they won't be able to check out a user's entire profile for further instances of *almost identical answers*. If you feel like it, take that task upon yourself, and **flag each occurrence**.

---

Related

- [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/289691)